# Rails API: One Request, Multiple Controller Actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have multiple models that in practice are created and deleted together.
Basically I have an Article model and an Authorship model. Authorships link the many to many relation between Users and Articles. When an Article is created, the corresponding Authorships are also created. Right now, this is being achieved by POSTing multiple times.

However, say only part of my request works. For instance, I'm on bad wifi and only the create article request makes it through. Then my data is in a malformed half created, half not state.

To solve this, I want to send all the data at once, then have Rails split up the data into the corresponding controllers. I've thought of a couple ways to do this. The first way is having controllers handle each request in turn, sort of chaining them together. This would require the controllers to call the next one in the chain. However, this seems sorta rigid because if I decide to compose the controllers in a different way, I'll have to actually modify the controller code itself.

The second way splits up the data first, then calls the controller actions with each bit of data. This way seems more clean to me, but it requires some logic either in the routing or in a layer independent of the controllers. I'm not really clear where this logic should go (another controller? Router? Middleware?)

Has anybody had experience with either method? Is there an even better way?

Thanks,
Nicholas

Answer (score 4):

Typically you want to do stuff like this -- creating associated records on object creation -- all in the same transaction. I would definitely not consider breaking up the creation of an `Authorship` and `Article` if creating an `Authorship` is automatic on `Article` creation. You want a single request that takes in all needed parameters to create an `Article` *and* its associated `Authorship`, then you create both in the same transaction. One way would be to do something like this in the controller:

```
class Authorship
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :article
end

class Article
  has_many :authorships
  has_many :users, through: :authorships
end

class ArticlesController
  def create
    @article = Article.new({title: params[:title], stuff: [:stuff]...})
    @article.authorships.build(article: @article, user_id: params[:user_id])
    if @article.save
      then do stuff...
    end
  end
end
```

This way when you hit `@article.save`, the processing of both the `Article` and the `Authorship` are part of the same transaction. So if something fails anywhere, then the whole thing fails, and you don't end up with stray/disparate/inconsistent data.

If you want to assign multiple authorships on the endpoint (i.e. you take in multiple user id params) then the last bit could become something like:

```
class ArticlesController
  def create
    @article = Article.new({title: params[:title], stuff: [:stuff]...})
    params[:user_ids].each do |id|
      @article.authorships.build(article: @article, user_id: id)
    end

    if @article.save
      then do stuff...
    end
  end
end
```

You can also offload this kind of associated object creation into the model via a virtual attribute and a `before_save` or `before_create` callback, which would also be transactional. But the above idiom seems more typical.

Comment: Okay, so build it in the Articles controller. That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would handle this in the model with one request.  If you have a `has_many` relationship between `Article` and `Author`, you may be able to use `accept_nested_attributes_for` on your `Article` model.  Then you can pass `Authorship` attributes along with your `Article` attributes in one request.

I have not seen your code, but you can do something like this:

**model/article.rb**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :authors, through: :authorship # you may also need a class_name: param
   accepts_nested_attributes_for: :authors
end
```

You can then pass `Author` attributes to the `Article` model and Rails will create/update the `Authors` as required.

Here is a good [blog post](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through) on accepts_nested_attributes_for.  You can read about it in the [official Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

I would recommend taking advantage of nested attributes and the association methods Rails gives you to handle of this with one web request inside one controller action.

Comment: Your `article.rb`'s first line looks a little skewiff. Perhaps you meant `class Article < ActiveRecord::Base`?